# Strengthening the Antecedent: From B implies C, infer (A ^ B) implies C

Tags: logic, proof-verification, propositional-calculus

How can I construct a Fitch style proof to prove this?
I have tried

> 1. B $\rightarrow$ C
>
>    2. A $\land$ B
>    3. B $\quad\quad$ $\land$ Elim: $2$
>    4. C $\quad\quad$ $\rightarrow$ Elim: $1,3$
>
> $5$. (A $\land$ B) $\rightarrow$ C $\quad\quad$ $\rightarrow$ Intro: $2-4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to indicate what kind of Elim and Intro you do:

Line 3 is an $\land$ Elim

Line4 is an $\rightarrow$ Elim

line 5 is an $\rightarrow $ Intro

Otherwise perfect!

Comment: Line 6 as an $\to$ Intro would complete it, but you might get away with it as is.

Answer (score 0):

So far, so good. You have only one more line to add to complete your proof: $(B\implies C) \implies ((A\land B) \implies C)$.

Comment: where exactly would you put that line

Comment: Where you usually put a conclusion. At the end.

Comment: I don't think that is needed. The OP needs to infer the one statement from the other, so in a Fitch style proof the one statement is a premise, and the other the conclusion.

Comment: But then you need to introduce the final implication: the resulting theorem.

Comment: @DanChristensen I really don't think so. The OP is asked to infer the one statement from the other, so there is a premise and a conclusion. The OP is not asked to prove a single statement to be a valid statement with no premises at all.

Comment: @Bram28 The purpose of a mathematical proof to derive a theorem, is it not?

Comment: @DanChristensen From axioms, sure. So then the axioms would be the premises, and the theorem the conclusion.